# buenas noches, para este codigo del juego de las seis ranas al mover una rana RV a la derecha se vuelve RM ES EN JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, matrices

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject9;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author marco
 */
class Game {
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;
    private static final int FROG = 1;

    private int[] board = {FROG, FROG, FROG, EMPTY, FROG, FROG, FROG};



    public void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                System.out.print("_ ");
            }
            if (board[i] == FROG) {
                System.out.print((i < 3) ? "MV " : "MF ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public boolean checkWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (board[i] == FROG) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isValidMove(int from, int to) {
        if (from < 0 || from >= board.length || to < 0 || to >= board.length) {
            return false;
        }

        if (board[from] == FROG && board[to] == EMPTY && Math.abs(from - to) <= 2) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void moveFrog(int from, int to) {
        if (isValidMove(from, to)) {
            board[from] = EMPTY;
            board[to] = FROG;
        } else {
            System.out.println("========================");
            System.out.println("Movimiento inválido.");
            System.out.println("========================");
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("¡Bienvenido al juego de las seis ranas!");

        while (!checkWin()) {
            printBoard();
            System.out.println("========================================================");
            System.out.println("Ingresa la posición de la rana que quieres mover (0-6):");
            System.out.println("========================================================");
            int from = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("========================================================");
            System.out.println("Ingresa la posición a la que quieres mover la rana (0-6):");
            System.out.println("========================================================");
            int to = scanner.nextInt();

            moveFrog(from, to);
        }

        printBoard();
        System.out.println("========================================================");
        System.out.println("¡Has ganado! ¡Todas las ranas han cruzado el estanque!");
        System.out.println("========================================================");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }
}
```

*es un codigo para el juego de las seis ranas el tablero es el siguiente MV MV MV _ MF MF MF teniendo en cuenta que una matriz inicia desde cero la primera rana MV seria 0 y la ultima rana MF seria 6 lo que sucede es que al mover la rana 2 al espacio 3 queda asi MV MV  _ MF MF MF MF pero necesito que quede asi MV MV _ MV MF MF MF  lo mismo sucede con la MF
este codigo esta hecho en netbeans 15 con java maven aplication*
***sé que el error está en la parte de public void printBoard() {  , pero no se solucionarlo***

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

Vamos con lo principal:

```
private static final int EMPTY = 0;
private static final int FROG = 1;
private int[] board = {FROG, FROG, FROG, EMPTY, FROG, FROG, FROG};
```

Esto ya nos plantea un problema, no distingo entre los dos tipos de ranas, deberías hacerlo así:

```
private int EMPTY = 0;
private int FROGa = 1;
private int FROGb = 2;

private int[] board = { FROGa, FROGa, FROGa, EMPTY, FROGb, FROGb, FROGb };
```

De esta forma, puedo determinar cuando se ha ganado la partida, osea, cuando todas las ranas "a" están en la derecha y todas las ranas "b" en la izquierda.

Hecho esto, me obliga a cambiar unas comprobaciones, por ejemplo esta:

```
 if( board[from] == FROG && board[to] == EMPTY && Math.abs(from - to) <= 2) {
```

por esta:

```
 if( board[from] != EMPTY && board[to] == EMPTY && Math.abs(from - to) <= 2) {
```

Con el "**!= EMPTY**", compruebo que sea rana, sin importar el tipo.

Para imprimir el tablero, podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
public void printBoard() {
    for( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {
        if( board[ i ] == 0 ) {
            System.out.print("_ ");
        }
        else if( board[ i ] == FROGa ) {
            System.out.print( "MV " );
        }
        else if( board[ i ] == FROGb ) {
            System.out.print( "MF " );
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Como verás, cambié algunos "**if**" por "**else if**", para evitar comprobaciones innecesarias.

A la hora de comprobar si ganó, debes verificarlo así:

```
public boolean checkWin() {
    if( board[ 3 ] != EMPTY ) {
        return false; 
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

           // si cualquiera de las 3 primeras posiciones, no tiene una rana "b"
           // devolvemos "false"
        if( i < 3 && board[ i ] != FROGb ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Espero no haberme equivocado en nada, más tarde lo reviso.

PD: verás que quité los "**static**" y "**final**" totalmente innecesarios.

Olvidé un cambio, en "**moveFrog**" cambiamos:

```
board[from] = EMPTY;
board[to] = FROG;

board[ to ] = board[ from ];
board[ from ] = EMPTY;
```

De esta forma, asignamos el valor correcto a la nueva posición.

Edición, modifiqué el método **checkWin** para realizar menos comprobaciones.

Comment: +1 Excelente explicación. Gracias por citar el fallo de identificación del tipo de rana, eso iba a comentar.

Comment: Gracias maestro, se lo extraña un poco por aquí, espero que se deba a temas laborales y no a problemas!!

Comment: yo simplificaria muchisimo el checkwin... no tiene sentido hacer un if, cuando la condicion de victoria es claramente 1 sola, y siempre la misma... alcanza con un if que sea algo asi: if (board[1] = board[2] = board[3] = frogb and board[4] = empty) entonces gano.... (obviamente, codigo muy simplificado)

Comment: @gbianchi, no está nada mal... me gusta!!.

Answer (score 0):

vamos a analizar tu funcion:

```
public void printBoard() {
    //recorremos el tablero
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        //si i es igual a 3... pero como, siempre??? y entonces para que tenemos un tablero?
        if (i == 3) {
            System.out.print("_ ");
        }
        //si hay una rana
        if (board[i] == FROG) {
            //pero, como, otra vez?? o sea las ranas mv no pueden estar en posiciones mayores a 3???
            System.out.print((i < 3) ? "MV " : "MF ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Para arreglar tu codigo, haria falta que lo leyera todo, y es muy largo, pero tus errores estan ahi... si el tablero debera saber como imprimirse porque sabe lo que tiene... y FROG deberia saber de que tipo es... y el _ deberia imprimirse donde no hay FROG...

O sea, como resumen, tu problema se resume a que tu tablero, no identifica bien las cosas... la posicion vacia, es vacia siempre, y no es posicional... y las ranas, tenes que saber cual es cual, para poder mostrar segun la rana que sea. No se hace nada segun la posicion en el tablero...

Comment: esto no es una respuesta, pudo ser un comentario. si el error es de lógica, no tiene sentido decir en esta línea hay un error sin decirle cual es la lógica correcta qué debe aplicar para alcanzar el objetivo.

Comment: Pero se la dije.. todo al final...

Comment: Y no le puedo reescribir mas, porque hay que reescribirle absolutamente TODO el codigo.. tiene errores en la concepcion del programa que hacen que no se pueda arreglar asi como asi... @ArcanisGK507

Comment: esoy interpretando que en tu respuesta señalas que esto esactamente del codigo esta mal: `(i < 3) ? "MV " : "MF "`; si esta mal cual seria la respuesta correcta, la logica correcta que debe aplicar para alcansar el objetivo?

Comment: tu mismo me enseñaste que señalar el error no es una solución ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 aca; "si el tablero debera saber como imprimirse porque sabe lo que tiene... y FROG deberia saber de que tipo es... y el _ deberia imprimirse donde no hay FROG..."... que no le haya escrito codigo, no quiere decir que no le haya dicho que hacer..